Is it dangerous to move aquatic snails?
I have some lovely aquatic snails.
The only issue is that I move between places semi-frequently. My current thought was that I can keep them in one aquarium for some time and then when I move I can just move them into a different tank.
However, I started thinking if maybe it would be stressful to move the snails. They wouldn't be moving very far or extremely often.
I am a little emotional over my buddies and want to make sure they all safe and taken care of at all times. Thank you so much for any help you can provide.
TL;DR Is it dangerous to change a snail's tank?

The chemistry of the two aquariums is different, so any living being moved from one aquarium to another will suffer some chemical / biological stress - additionally to the stress of you physically interacting with them.
Metaphorically, it is like you moving occasionally from the village to the city and then back.
